# Block Internet connection for Windows 7 using C#

Tags: c#, .net, networking

Is there a way to block Internet access to my PC by writing code in C#?

I'm using Windows 7, a way to control the firewall will also help. I've seen solutions for Windows XP and Windows Vista, but I didn't find any for '7'.

Comment: I add some more information to my answer that might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the WMI class `Win32_NetworkAdapter` to disable/enable the network adapter.

Here's a link to info about that class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Edit: Due to comment said that you only want to disable incoming traffic.

If you want to disable only incoming traffic I think you might have to use the `Windows Firewall API`, I've never used it so I'm not sure if it would be able to do that but seems plausible, and it is Win 7 compatible as far as I can tell.

Here's a link to it (I'd suggest the VBscript samples might be easier to translate to C# than the C++ samples):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366453%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: hey thanks a lot ho..really helping my cause..still going through the links..will ask if i have any further doubts..thanks a ton.!:)